# Ошибка: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture (мобильный Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, мобильная-разработка, ionic

Делаем приложение через Ionic/Cordova; компилю на платформу browser; через библиотeку медиа пытаюсь запустить мелодию по событию (пришел заказ от клиента).

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: если `PUSH` работает нормально, то на попытку инициализировать звук когда открыто приложение через мобильный хром — ну ни как не получается. Вылетает такая ошибка:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a
>   user gesture.

И да, я читал, что это такое и немного [вот об этом](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138132) и [этом](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178297).

Понаходил советы, что нужно вызов проигрывания цеплять на click или другой жест. Но, при всех прочих, захожу в ВК с мобильного браузера, смотрю на страницу — мне присылают сообщение, и звук идёт (не от `PUSH`, а от браузера)!

Вопрос: как у них это получилось? И как мне сделать такое же (хотя бы в теории)?
Буду рад любым идеям. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function initAudioItems(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent !== undefined) {
            var dom_item = document.getElementById('my_audio');
            dom_item.muted = true;
            dom_item.play()
                .catch(function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });
            dom_item.pause();
            dom_item.muted = false;
            $(dom_item).data('init', true);
        $('body').off('click', initAudioItems);
    }
}
// init audio
$('body').on('click', initAudioItems);
```

Если пользователь хоть раз кликнет на странице - аудио беззвучно запустится и остановится. После этого вы можете запускать его по произвольному событию.

Как ни старался не смог найти как такую инициализацию повесить на пролистывание, только на клик работает.

Answer (score 3):

Вы на полпути к решению, осталась только одна деталь - сохранение дом элемента audio для повторного использования.

Этот объект достаточно инициализировать лишь один раз в контексте пользовательского действия (нажатие или даже пролистывание), а затем использовать его везде где нужно запустить воспроизведение по произвольному событию.

Естественно на сайтах-одностраничниках такой "фокус" работает просто на ура, но не будет работать на сайтах которые перезагружают страницу полностью.

А также этот элемент после инициализации можно перемещать в DOM документа

Все вышесказанное относится как к сайту так и к приложению. Знаю что есть опция в настройках cordova разрешающая автовоспоизведение без взаимодействия с пользователем, но к сожалению она не на всех версиях android работает так как должна.

Comment: спасибо мысль натолкнула на решение проблемы, и решил ее )) юху-у-у))

Comment: не работает, ни по нажатию, ни по пролистыванию... Как Вы решили эту проблему? У меня видео должно проигрываться при загрузке страницы. play() в мобильном хроме работает ТОЛЬКО по нажатию кнопки ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕМ. Автоматическое вызывание .click() не срабатывает...